# data type int only stays positive till 2^31, as soon as it hits 2^32 it becomes negative, idk why?

Tags: c

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int bin[32] = {1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    int i = 31;
    int j;
    j = 0;
    int decNum = 0;
    while(i >= 0)
    {
        if(bin[i] == 1)
        {
            decNum += (pow(2,j));
        }
        j++;
        i--;
    }
    printf("%d", decNum);
}
```

Its suppose to print: 4098183680
but it prints: -196783616

```
increments of decNum: 512     4608    20992   86528   348672  4542976 71651840        340087296       876958208       1950700032      -196783616
```

Comment: Behaviour of `signed int`s overflow is not defined by the C standard. But to see how is "wrapped around" on most implementations take a look to https://compsecurityconcepts.wordpress.com/tag/integer-overflow/

Comment: Search for "twos-complement" or "integer overflow"

Answer (score 1):

int is a signed variable it ranges from -(2^31) to (2^31)-1

If you want only unsigned variables declare a unsigned int

or even better ...

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t myvar = 0;
```

where in uint32_t -> u stands for unsigned, 32 indicates the bit size of the variable

Comment: "_`int` is a signed variable it ranges from -(2^31) to (2^31)-1_": C `int`s have a _minimum_ range of -(2^15 - 1) to (2^15 - 1), but the actual range is an implementation detail.